# send multiple selected option withour sorting to php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

hi i have one issue with select with multiple select 
generally multiple select work on array when we select some option and send it to php so we get that arrya with sorting base on its index

my question is i have one multiple select with 5 options when i select with this order like 3 1 4 2 and send it to php so i get 1 2 3 4 but i want that order which i send from html

my html code is

```
<select class="chosen" id="location" name="location[]" multiple="multiple">
                            <option>Select</option>
                            <option value="OpenApp">OpenApp</option>
                            <option value="StartGame">StartGame</option>
                            <option value="EndGame">EndGame</option>
                            <option value="Reward_Calendar">Reward Calendar</option>
                            <option value="InviteFriend">InviteFriend</option>
                            <option value="Gift">Gift</option>
                            <option value="Store_Hot_Deals">Store Hot Deals</option>
                        </select>
```

and in php i get that array and prin it and i get this output

[image]

and in php output is

```
Array ( [0] => OpenApp [1] => StartGame [2] => EndGame [3] => Gift )
```

plese help me for this issue
thanks

Comment: try this code [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FjET4/161/)

Comment: if my link works for you please comment then i will post my answer

Comment: your link work same as my code buddy

Comment: is it useful for you or not ?

Comment: i target this part of your question **my question is i have one multiple select with 5 options when i select with this order like 3 1 4 2 and send it to php so i get 1 2 3 4 but i want that order which i send from html**

Comment: i want to send like 3 2 1 4 this order but in php i get 1 2 3 4 i want to get which i select first

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

On the selection of each option put the selected value in a JS Object and push the selected value in it for each selection. And post it to the server you will the proper order on server by using this object.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var obj = [];
    $('#select').click(function(){
    obj.push($(this).val());

    alert(obj);
  });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76qabk1a/6/)

Comment: i think your answer is helpful but i need example with select tag so i will know that how exactly your code is work

Comment: dont worry i understand what you want to say me now i get idea from your code thaks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about the final esult you want to achive, but of course you can't do it this way.
Php parses the post data "location"  in its original order and add to the array all the selected values.
So the only way I can think is moving up or down the options via js or jquery before sending the post.

```
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>
<form method="post">
    <select class="chosen" id="location" name="location[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Select</option>
        <option value="OpenApp">OpenApp</option>
        <option value="StartGame">StartGame</option>
        <option value="EndGame">EndGame</option>
        <option value="Reward_Calendar">Reward Calendar</option>
        <option value="InviteFriend">InviteFriend</option>
        <option value="Gift">Gift</option>
        <option value="Store_Hot_Deals">Store Hot Deals</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
<input type="button" value="Up">
<input type="button" value="Down">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
            var $op = $('#location option:selected'),
            $this = $(this);
            if($op.length){
                ($this.val() == 'Up') ? 
                $op.first().prev().before($op) : 
                $op.last().next().after($op);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/giacomopittalis/ofLuywnd/